# Django model filters stored in database

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working with content types in feincms. And I want to make a content type that can store filters in the database.
Roughly it would look like this:

```
from news.models import Entry
class NewsContent(models.Model):
    filter = models.CharField()
    exclude = models.CharField()
    offset = models.IntegerField()
    limit = models.IntegerField()
    #template = models.CharField()

    def get_entries(self):  
        return Entry.objects.filter(self.filter).exclude(self.exclude)[self.offset:self.limit_upper]
```

Is this possible?

Now this may or may not be a good idea speed wise, but that's question #2

Comment: What would example values of filter look like? I'd guess you'd have to parse them as Python code, which would be a very, very bad idea.

Comment: lol, I'm actually very tempted to do that, since I'll be the only one with access. But how about serialize or something like that? Maybe I can make dictionaries into filters somehow... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do that using a dictionary for the filter and exclude fields.

Say you want to add this filter:

```
...filter(one='asdf', two='xyz')
```

then you would store

```
"{'one':'asdf', 'two':'xyz'}"
```

as a string in your filter field of your NewsContentModel.

then you could do this

```
def get_entries(self):
    return Entry.objects.filter(**eval(self.filter))
```

I think that should work...

Comment: There is still the security issue with eval. But you're saying this: ...filter({one:'asdf', two:'xyz'})
would actually work?

Comment: filter({'one':'asdf', 'two':'xyz'}) would not work, but filter(**{'one':'asdf', 'two':'xyz'}) would.  Anytime you "eval" anything you don't trust, there is a risk...

Comment: ...also, you may be able to use pickle to serialize/deserialize your filter dictionary if you want to avoid using eval.

Comment: You should probably use a proper JSON encoder/decoder for that. It isn't too hard to build a Form class able to edit JSON data through automatically generated form fields either.