# Storing and escaping Django tags and filters in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am outputting content from my models to my templates, however some model fields call data stored in other models. This happens only in a few fields. I am wondering whether using an `if` tag to evaluate this would be more efficient compared to storing the django tags inside the models.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503689/django-model-filters-stored-in-database) say that storing django tags in models is a bad idea without giving reasons (although I think one of the reasons may be someone else may inject some tags in the Database). Assuming that database injection is a rarity, is there a way of escaping Django tags and filters stored in a model.

Or better yet, what would be the most efficient method to handle the above situation where one model field in several fields calls fields stored in another model.

*Example*:

This should be stored in my models

```
<p>We focus on:</p>
{% for item in services %}
{% url service_view item.id as service_url %}
<ul>
<li><a href="service_url">{{item.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Outputting it should result in django parsing the relevant django tags as if part of the template

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.  "Tags stored in the database"? Could you give us some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ned, I tried implementing that but I found it to be quite complex and its also disadvantageous in terms of portability.

However, I found exactly what I needed at Django Snippets (dont know why I didn't look there first). Its a quite useful utility known as [render_as_template](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1373/).

After setting it up as a custom tag, all that I needed was to use it in the form `{% render_as_template about_view.content %}` and the tags in the models were rendered as models.

Instructions on creating your own custom templates and tags [available here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

[django-dbtemplates](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbtemplates) probably comes close to doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) and then include that tag wherever you'd like the html to be rendered.  The model should just be generating values for the variables, not formatting.

Comment: how does this work? The motive of the whole problem case is to include  output from another model in a few fields from another model. When doing this, I want to maintain performance by avoiding a loop that keeps executing to check if the field calls other models. To avoid the  loop, I save the data in the field with code to call related fields from another model.