# Using variables in Django model content

Tags: python, django

i like to use the url template tag in my model's content.

example:

**models content:**

```
Car.description = 'this is a link to our main page: <a href="{url home}">home</a>'
```

**in template.html:**

```
<div>{{ Car.description }}</div>
```

**result**

```
<div>this is a link to our main page: <a href="/">home</a>
```

is it possible, or do i have to write my own template tag?

thanks in advance
Roman

Comment: i found this in "related" box on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594909/storing-and-escaping-django-tags-and-filters-in-django-models?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out why you would need to do that. Assuming that I fully-understood your question, you are attempting to store something within a model's field that then behaves "dynamically" when rendered.

A model field's content that stores a URL should contain a URL and only a URL by utilizing the [`URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield).

Else, if you're dynamically building the URL from somewhere else, simply use template markup, i.e. the `url` template tag as it is meant to be used; it can also take parameters depending on the specific URL pattern. I.e. the `url` tag is meant to be used in the template's context.

Let me know if you update the question to describe what you are trying to achieve. But storing "behaviour" at data level is something to simply stay away from.

Comment: i just want to store an internal link in the car's description.
to ensure that it is valid when the url changes, i need to use the {{ url }} template tag behaviour. or is it possible to use template tags in a model field?

Comment: Can't you store the link on it's own and then render it as usual at template level?

Comment: it has to be in the text, and a user should be able to set another link. a wiki is a better example.

Comment: Then IMO it would be better to store the full URL at DB level (rather than a "renderable" URL tag) and then use [`autoescape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape).

Comment: Or else utilize @mariodev answer; it achieves what you want; the additional cost being that you will be rendering a template within a template. But if performance is not a problem, that might be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: OK, i'll give both a template-tags and a custom model property a try
Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this:

```
car.description = 'this is a link to our main page: <a href="{{ url }}">home</a>'
```

You can do:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class Car(models.Model):
    def description_with_url(self):
        return Template(self.description).render({'url': reverse('home')})
```

or use the same logic in custom template tag instead of method..